# How do I save newly made pictures with a prefix name and an iteration number

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, prefix

i am creating a function to create coloured square tiles dependent on the function createSquareTile(numTiles, prefix). How do i make sure that the file is saved under a certain prefix mentioned when calling the function and also the number of times it has been made. Also, how do i loop these codes according to the number of times that is mentioned in 'numTiles'?

Eg. createSquareTile(2, squaretile), it will create 2 tiles and saved as squaretile1, squaretile2

numTiles = number of tiles to be made

prefix = prefix name for tiles to be saved as

code:

```
def createSquareTile(numTiles, prefix):
  current = 1 #iteration number
  if current == 1: #Checks if first tile created
    size = requestNumber("Please input a positive number")
    sizeI = int(size)

  while (sizeI < 0): #If invalid input 
      showError("Your input number" + str(sizeI)+ "is not valid. Do it again!")
      size = requestNumber("Please input a positive number")

    if (sizeI > 0): #if input number is positive
      current = current + 1
      color = pickAColor()
      newTile = makeEmptyPicture(sizeI, sizeI, color)
      setMediaPath()
      writePictureTo(newTile, getMediaPath(string(prefix) + current))

  elif current > 1: #Checks if not first tile created
    previousChoice = requestString("Same size as pervious tile? (Y/N)")

    while (previous != "N") and (previous != "Y"):
      showError("Your input character" + previousChoice + "is not valid. Do it again!")
      previousChoice = requestString("Same size as previous tile? (Y/N)")

    if (previousChoice == "Y"): #If user wants to create the next tile with the same size as the previous
      current = current + 1
      colorY = pickAColor()
      newTileY = makeEmptyPicture(sizeI, sizeI, colorY)
      setMediaPath()
      writePictureTo(newTileY, getMediaPath(string(prefix)+ current))


    elif (previousChoice == "N"): #If not the first title made and user does not want previous size
      sizeN = requestNumber("Please input a positive size number")
      sizeNI = int(numTilesN)
      current = current + 1
      colorN = pickAColor()
      newTileN = makeEmptyPicture(sizeNI, sizeNI, colorN)
      setMediaPath()
      writePictureTo(newTileN, getMediaPath(string(prefix)+ current))
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Why wouldn't `for n in range...` work?

Comment: @Jacob Ah yes, i was having trouble in finding what range to run it in but i've found that  `for i in range(numTiles)`  works! Thanks!